# When I sign a transaction or generate a payload, what is the appropriate/suggested value for the field called “Era Period”?

Tags: transactions, era

I read the documentation in the [wiki](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-protocol-info#transaction-mortality) and the [support docs](https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000168050-what-is-an-era-) so I know that in Polkadot I can set any value bigger than zero and smaller/equal to 2400 to create a valid mortal transaction.

However I was wondering if there is an appropriate/suggested value for this parameter? Do I have to change this value based on each specific situation or use case ?

Answer (score 1):

The value for the “Era Period” field will generally depend on how many blocks you expect between construction (when the checkpoint block is chosen) and broadcast. If you expect it to take one hour, then you could set it to 600 (600 blocks/hour).

Note that it rounds up to the next power of 2, so setting 600 would actually be 1024.